# Ubuntu 16.10 automatically logs out after loading desktop, dock, background picture

Tags: xubuntu, login, shutdown, 16.10

I've tried removing .Xauthority, force-updating libssl, reinstalling Ubuntu completely, "sudo dpkg --configure -a", and a few other ideas people offered. I can access Guest or another account I created, but not my account. It just kicks back out to login screen.

What logs are helpful for diagnosing this problem?

What more can I do?

Possible causes are trying xubuntu-desktop (since uninstalled), and battery running down causing system to force itself to shut down (Ubuntu's not so good with BIOS, sleep, and shutdowns).

Comment: Try guest account right after you get kicked out to rule out or rule in low battery.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix It's ongoing, repeatable at least dozens of times. Battery has no effect, it always kicks out my account, and always allows guest login or alternate account login. I was saying that potentially a battery running out and improper shutdown may have started the problem.

Comment: Ah yes I see that now. Originally I was reading it on my phone.